# The use of "of" in this sentence

Tags: possessives

> A cramped Brooklyn outlet **of** Barnes & Noble, a book chain, requires strollers to be left in a designated parking space on the second floor.

I don't know how *of* is used in that sentence. Could someone make other combinations using *of* in the same way?

Comment: This is the **most basic** use of the preposition, connoting ownership. Does your dictionary not provide a definition of the preposition _of?_

Comment: I think it's the same with "the city of love.".What do you think?@P.E.Dant

Comment: Again: what does your English language dictionary tell you about the preposition _of?_ What does it mean?

Comment: Used to indicate apposition or identity?Like  "idiot of a salesman"??@P.E.Dant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the Brooklyn outlet is one of the many outlets of Barnes and Noble.

Comment: But Barnes and Noble is a book store name..

Comment: @vancake What does your dictionary tell you about the preposition _of?_ What does it mean? Hint: _Washington D.C. is the capital **of** the United States._

Comment: I know this sentence @P.E.Dant

Comment: @vancake Barnes and Noble is not 'a' bookstore: it is a corporation which operates more than 600 bookstores--retail outlets.

Comment: thanks..I got it..I did not know the meaning of outlets ...@StoneyB